# How to write a stop function for iOS AudioServices in this Phonegap plugin?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, plugins, cordova

I'm using the [Phonegap plugin SoundPlug to manage my audio](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SoundPlug) within this HTML5 game I'm building, and although it comes with a way to play a sound, it doesn't have any methods for stopping a sound. The play function is called from your app's javascript with PhoneGap.exec("SoundPlug.play","sound.wav"). The relevant code looks like this:

```
- (void) play:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSMutableArray *directoryParts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[(NSString*)[arguments objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
    NSString       *filename       = [directoryParts lastObject];
    [directoryParts removeLastObject];

    NSMutableArray *filenameParts  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]];
    NSString *directoryStr = [directoryParts componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];

    NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:(NSString*)[filenameParts objectAtIndex:0]
                                              ofType:(NSString*)[filenameParts objectAtIndex:1]
                                         inDirectory:directoryStr];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)fileURL, &soundID);   
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

I unfortunately don't know anything about Obj-C, so I'm unsure how to write an appropriate stop function for this. (The precise situation I'm trying to handle is when a player wants to mute all running sounds.)

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound if you need to stop it.  If phonegap has a bridge to AVAudioPlayer, that is probably a more suitable API to use for starting and stoping sounds.

But if you save the soundID variable used by AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() somewhere (in an instance variable, global variable, or passed back to webview-javascript-land, etc.); AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID) might stop the system sound being produced by that soundID.